# How do I create a regularly-spaced array of values in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

How do I make an array that's defined with a start point, an end point, and a total array size? Something like an array that goes from 1 to 10 that's 20 elements long. For example, the array could look something like:

```
1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 ...
```

Comment: In the sample vector you give, moving from 1 to 10 in steps of 0.5 would give you a 19 element vector, not 20.

Comment: 19 - I counted on my fingers. Couldn't find my abacus.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this:

- Using the [colon operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html):

  ```
  startValue = 1;
  endValue = 10;
  nElements = 20;
  stepSize = (endValue-startValue)/(nElements-1);
  A = startValue:stepSize:endValue;
  ```
- Using the [`linspace`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) function (as suggested by [Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1853950/52738)):

  ```
  startValue = 1;
  endValue = 10;
  nElements = 20;
  A = linspace(startValue,endValue,nElements);
  ```

Keep in mind that the number of elements in the resulting arrays *includes* the end points. In the above examples, the difference between array element values will be `9/19`, or a little *less than* `0.5` (unlike the sample array in the question).

Answer (score 10):

[linspace](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/linspace.html) generates linearly spaced vectors:

```
>>  A = linspace(1, 10, 20-1)
ans =
1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 ... 9.5 10
```

Comment: n.b. `linspace` outputs *row* vectors; here in optimization land, all vectors are column vectors. beware.

Comment: the OP want to create an array with 20 elements and you're talking about some negligible optimization (which may not even be the case!!)

Answer (score 6):

Simple one-liner!

```
1:0.5:10;
```

Output:

```
1 1.5 2 2.5 ... 9 9.5 10
```

Note that this would be a 19-element vector, not 20.

Comment: No, this would be a *19-element* vector. It would include the integers 1 to 10 (of which there are 10), along with the midpoints between each pair of integers (of which there are 9).