# MATLAB: get equally spaced entries of Vector

Tags: matlab, vector, distance, space

How would it be possible to get equally spaced entries from a Vector in MATLAB, e.g. I have the following vector:

```
 0    25    50    75   100   125   150
```

When I chose `2` I want to get:

```
0   150
```

When I chose `3` I want to get:

```
0   75   150
```

When I chose `4` I want to get:

```
0   50   100   150
```

Chosing `1`, `5` or `6` shouldn't work and I even need a check for an `if`-clause for that but I can't figure this out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a regularly-spaced array of values in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853891/how-do-i-create-a-regularly-spaced-array-of-values-in-matlab)

Comment: nope as I can see not and therefore also neither to be voted "close"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate the indices with `linspace` and `round`:

```
vector = [0    25    50    75   100   125   150]; % // data
n = 4; % // desired number of equally spaced entries

ind = round(linspace(1,length(vector),n)); %// get rounded equally spaced indices
result = vector(ind) % // apply indices to the data vector
```

If you want to force that values 1, 5 or 6 for `n` don't work: test if `n-1` divides `length(vector)-1)`. If you do that you don't need `round` to obtain the indices:

```
if rem((length(vector)-1)/(n-1), 1) ~= 0
    error('Value of n not allowed')
end
ind = linspace(1,length(vector),n); %// get equally spaced indices
result = vector(ind) % // apply indices to the data vector
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [linspace](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html):

```
>> a
a =

     0    25    50    75   100   125   150

>> a(linspace(1,length(a),4))
ans =

     0    50   100   150

>> a(linspace(1,length(a),3))
ans =

     0    75   150

>> a(linspace(1,length(a),2))
ans =

     0   150
```

Note that, except for 1, the invalid values raise an error:

```
>> a(linspace(1,length(a),5))
error: subscript indices must be either positive integers or logicals
>> a(linspace(1,length(a),6))
error: subscript indices must be either positive integers or logicals
```