# Concise way to create an array filled within a range in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I need to create an array filled within a range in Matlab

e.g.

```
from=2
to=6
increment=1
```

result

```
[2,3,4,5,6]
```

e.g.

```
from=15
to=25
increment=2
```

result

```
[15,17,19,21,23,25]
```

Obviously I can create a loop to perform this action from scratch but I wondering if there is a coincise and efficent way to do this with built-in matlab commands since seems a very common operation

**EDIT**

If I use linspace the operation is weird since the spacing between the points is `(x2-x1)/(n-1)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a regularly-spaced array of values in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853891/how-do-i-create-a-regularly-spaced-array-of-values-in-matlab)

Comment: @TroyHaskin its close but not exact dupe as this is about `start,increment,end` while that one is about `start,end,no_of_elem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be handled simply by the `:` operator in the following notation

```
array = from:increment:to
```

Note that the increment defaults to 1 if written with only one colon seperator

```
array = from:to
```

**Example**

```
array1 = 2:6          %Produces [2,3,4,5,6]
array2 = 15:2:25      %Produces [15,17,19,21,23,25]
```

Comment: if I call a function that passes from and to values I get the error Not enough input arguments.