# Vector with specific number of equally spaced values

Tags: matlab, vector

I am familiar with the command:

```
(-5:0.1:5)
```

which creates a vector of values, equally spaced by 0.1, from -5 to 5.

However, is there a way to produce a vector of values, equally spaced from -5 to 5 such that there are, say, 100 values in the vector.

(-5:0.1:5) gives a vector with 101 values, however, is there a way to get a vector of 100 values without manually calculating the step size?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a regularly-spaced array of values in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853891/how-do-i-create-a-regularly-spaced-array-of-values-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Use function `linspace`. See documentation [here](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html)

```
linspace(1,10,10)
```

ans =

```
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

also the question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853891/how-do-i-create-a-regularly-spaced-array-of-values-in-matlab) question